# Would there be complications to use both fgets() and fscanf() to read the same file?

Tags: c, file, scanf, fgets

I'm writing the information of an array of struct in to a file and then convert the content of the file to a new struct. My code will write the array of struct `port_table` to a file in the following format:

```
3
port_A 0
port_B 1
port_C 2
...
```

The first line is a number indicating the total number of ports listed in the file. And I will use this number to declare the array size for the new struct. Followed by this number is a list of `port_name` (string) and the `port_number` (uint32_t).

I can write the information to the file but I had trouble reading the file. Particularly, I don't know how to read just the first line and store that as a variable and load the actual list of ports into the new struct `transfered_port_table`. I tried the following code which I just used `fgets()` to read the first line of the file to get the size info. And used `fscanf()` to load the list into the struct:

```
    int j = 0;
    char str_size[50] = {0};

    fp = fopen("/home/davie/Desktop/tmp", "r");
    if(!fp){
        printf("Failed to open file. Program exit");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Getting the string version of the number of ports from the file
    if(fgets(str_size, 50, fp) != NULL){
        printf("size: %s\n", str_size);
    }

    // Convert the string version of the number of ports to int
    int size_int = strtol(str_size, NULL, 10);
    printf("size in int: %d\n", size_int);

    //Declare the new array of struct
    transfered_port_table_t transfered_port_table[size_int];

    for (j = 0; j < size_int; j++) {
        if (!read_data_from_file(fp, &transfered_port_table[j])) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

I totally did not expect this to work but from the print out, it did work. I thing that `fgets()` only read till it hit '\0' or '\n', and the `fscanf()` will also try to read the first line of the file and error out since it does not match the format I provided. But **I don't know why the code is working**. It makes me nervous that I'm over looking something. This piece of code needs to be really robust and be able to handle a long list of ports. So I'd like to know why this code is working or it's just a fluke. Is there any danger to do so. **Additionally, please provide any advice on how to make this code robust if you notice anything that can lead to error.**
Thank you!

Code out put:

```
size: 3

size in int: 3
port_A 0
port_B 1
port_C 2
Successfully deleted file
port_A 0
port_B 1
port_C 2
Found
```

Full code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PORT_A_NUM                                  0x00000000
#define PORT_B_NUM                                  0x00000001
#define PORT_C_NUM                                  0x00000002

#define PORT_A "port_A"
#define PORT_B "port_B"
#define PORT_C "port_C"

#define SIZE_OF_PORT_TABLE (sizeof(port_table)/sizeof(port_table_t))
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 100
/**original table***/
struct port_table_s {
    const char* name;
    uint32_t number;
};

typedef struct port_table_s port_table_t;
static port_table_t port_table[] = {
    {PORT_A, PORT_A_NUM},
    {PORT_B, PORT_B_NUM},
    {PORT_C, PORT_C_NUM}
};


/***transfered table 2****/
typedef struct transfered_port_table_s {
    char port_name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    uint32_t port_number;
}transfered_port_table_t;

int read_data_from_file(FILE *fp, transfered_port_table_t *arr)  
{  
    return fscanf(fp, "%s %d", arr->port_name, &arr->port_number) == 2;
}

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    // write to file
    fp = fopen ("/home/davie/Desktop/tmp", "w");
    if(!fp){
        printf("Failed to open file. Program exit");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    fprintf(fp, "%ld\n", SIZE_OF_PORT_TABLE);
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_PORT_TABLE; i++){ // I can use the SIZE_OF_PORT_TABLE when writing to the file, but not when reading the file
        fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", port_table[i].name, port_table[i].number);
    }
    fclose(fp);


    // read from file
    int j = 0;
    char str_size[50] = {0};

    fp = fopen("/home/davie/Desktop/tmp", "r");
    if(!fp){
        printf("Failed to open file. Program exit");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Getting the string version of the number of ports from the file
    if(fgets(str_size, 50, fp) != NULL){
        printf("size: %s\n", str_size);
    }

    // Convert the string version of the number of ports to int
    int size_int = strtol(str_size, NULL, 10);
    printf("size in int: %d\n", size_int);

    //Declare the new array of struct
    transfered_port_table_t transfered_port_table[size_int];

    for (j = 0; j < size_int; j++) {
        if (!read_data_from_file(fp, &transfered_port_table[j])) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    
    // Check if all line read 
    if (j != size_int) {
        fprintf(stderr, "only read %d ports out of %d\n", j, size_int);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Check if the new struct array is loaded by printing each element out 
    for(int g = 0; g < size_int; g++){
        printf("%s %d\n", transfered_port_table[g].port_name, transfered_port_table[g].port_number);
    }

    // Try removing the file and then see if the stuct can still be printed
    if(remove("/home/davie/Desktop/tmp") == 0){
        printf("Successfully deleted file\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to deleted file\n");
    }

    // Check if we can find a specific port here
    for(int g = 0; g < size_int; g++){
        printf("%s %d\n", transfered_port_table[g].port_name, transfered_port_table[g].port_number);
        if(transfered_port_table[g].port_number == PORT_C_NUM){
            printf("Found\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Update approach using `fgets()` and `sscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PORT_A_NUM                                  0x00000000
#define PORT_B_NUM                                  0x00000001
#define PORT_C_NUM                                  0x00000002

#define PORT_A "port_A"
#define PORT_B "port_B"
#define PORT_C "port_C"

#define SIZE_OF_PORT_TABLE (sizeof(port_table)/sizeof(port_table_t))
#define MAX_NAME_BUFFER_SIZE 200
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 100
/**original table***/
struct port_table_s {
    const char* name;
    uint32_t number;
};

typedef struct port_table_s port_table_t;
static port_table_t port_table[] = {
    {PORT_A, PORT_A_NUM},
    {PORT_B, PORT_B_NUM},
    {PORT_C, PORT_C_NUM}
};


/***transfered table 2****/
typedef struct transfered_port_table_s {
    char port_name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    uint32_t port_number;
}transfered_port_table_t;

int read_data_from_file(FILE *fp, transfered_port_table_t *arr)  
{  
    return fscanf(fp, "%s %d", arr->port_name, &arr->port_number) == 2;
}

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    // write to file
    fp = fopen ("/home/davie/Desktop/tmp", "w");
    if(!fp){
        printf("Failed to open file. Program exit");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fp, "%ld\n", SIZE_OF_PORT_TABLE);
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_PORT_TABLE; i++){ // I can use the SIZE_OF_PORT_TABLE when writing to the file, but not when reading the file
        fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", port_table[i].name, port_table[i].number);
    }
    fclose(fp);


    // read from file
    int j = 0;
    char str_size[50] = {0};
    char read_line_buffer[MAX_NAME_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

    fp = fopen("/home/davie/Desktop/tmp", "r");
    if(!fp){
        printf("Failed to open file. Program exit");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Getting the string version of the number of ports from the file
    if(fgets(str_size, 50, fp) != NULL){
        printf("size: %s", str_size);
    }

    // Convert the string version of the number of ports to int
    int size_int = strtol(str_size, NULL, 10);
    printf("size in int: %d\n", size_int);

    //Declare the new array of struct
    transfered_port_table_t transfered_port_table[size_int];

    while(fgets(read_line_buffer, sizeof(read_line_buffer), fp)){
        int ret = sscanf(read_line_buffer, "%s %d", transfered_port_table[j].port_name, &transfered_port_table[j].port_number);
        if(ret < 2){
            // Intentional 
            printf("Failed to %d cell in transfered_table", j);
        }
        j++;
    }
    if(j < size_int){
        printf("Only %d out of %d port is read", j, size_int);
    }

    // Check if the new struct array is loaded by printing each element out 
    for(int g = 0; g < size_int; g++){
        printf("%s %d\n", transfered_port_table[g].port_name, transfered_port_table[g].port_number);
    }

    // Try removing the file and then see if the stuct can still be printed
    if(remove("/home/davie/Desktop/tmp") == 0){
        printf("Successfully deleted file\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to deleted file\n");
    }

    // Check if we can find a specific port here
    for(int g = 0; g < size_int; g++){
        printf("%s %d\n", transfered_port_table[g].port_name, transfered_port_table[g].port_number);
        if(transfered_port_table[g].port_number == PORT_C_NUM){
            printf("Found\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would advice `fgets` & `sscanf` combination

Comment: "*I thing that fgets() only read till it hit '\0' or '\n', and the fscanf() will also try to read the first line of the file*". That isn't what happens. `fscanf` will not read the first line again because `fgets` has already read it. The file position is associated with the `FILE *`. Since both function use the same file pointer one will continue where the other left off.

Comment: Complications? Yes. They have different characteristics and you should not mix them unless you are very familiar with their intricacies. If you had to ask, then you probably are not. If you don't know why it is working, then you won't know under what conditions it fails, and so there is no way you have "robust code".

Comment: I'll add to @WeatherVane's comment:  Even if you think you know the intricacies, any of the `scanf()` family of functions is likely to surprise you when it encounters some obscure combination of input.  And when one of the `scanf()` families fails, there's no way to tell where in the input stream it stopped, so there's no reliable way to recover.

Comment: Using `fscanf` all by itself can cause "complications".

Comment: It is indeed most definitely true that *scanf and fgets do not play nicely together.  The general advice is to use *scanf to read all of your input, or none of it.  (But using fgets to read all of it, and then secondarily parsing some/all lines using sscanf, is fine.)

Comment: Code updated with ```fgets()``` and ```sscanf()```